# Websockets and python django

Tags: react-native, websocket, django-rest-framework, xmpp

So, possibly my questions are a bit stupid, but never mind. I am programming an app with React Native and the Django Rest Framework. Now I want to build a chat feature that allows you to write in real time (Like Instagram Direct Messages). I've heard a lot of terms like XMPP or Websockets, but not really an explanation of what is what. How does it work with websockets and is it possible with the Django Rest Framework?

## Edit

I now know how websockets works. But is there a way to do this without e.g. Django Channels? :) Like to do everything from scratch?

Comment: This is done through *Django chennels* https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: But how can I do this with the Rest Framework. Is this possible? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could but this would be very dumb. Django Channels is great to build fast and good **Websockets**. The **Django REST Framework** is a **HTTP REST Framework** and cannot create a TCP Connection, etc.